# PHP Code (With XAMPP) Config.php

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I am using XAMMP, PHPMyAdmin, Notepad++ on a Windows 7 computer (64-bit).

I am attempting to make a login page for my website, using this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-a-signup-form-with-email-confirmation/

However, I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in ...\XAMPP\htdocs\EP\inc\php\config.php on line 4
>   I couldn't connect to your database, please make sure your info is correct!

This is my code:

```
//connect to the database
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die("I couldn't connect to your database, please make sure your info is correct!");
mysql_select_db('registration') or die("I couldn't find the database table ($table) make sure it's spelt right!");
```

I have absolutely no idea what username and password are supposed to mean and I am unsure if the 'localhost' is supposed to be my IP.

Comment: We need to see your code, but, localhost is ok to your local connection, try changing your user to "root" (without quotes) and password empty (or "root" too if empty doesn´t work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting the data thus:

```
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root','') or die ("here you put whatever you want");
```

Usually this is the default access.